# Why it always turn into black screen when I turn on my PC

Tags: windows

My laptop is Acer Swift windows 10 I just bought it like 2 months ago. When I turn it on, it runs well after 'Welcome' and show up user name it should be run to windows but sadly it turn out black screen and there was my cursor there, and I try to use alt + ctrl + del after that it was laoding to the windows, and it was always like that, Can someone help me ? so I can turn off and turn it on normally like usual without that ctrl alt del

Comment: Your question is unclear - you may want to explain what works and doesn't more clearly, and/or add some pictures.  (Maybe you can take them from your cellphone?)

Comment: what i wanna ask is how can I boot my laptop normally without ctrl alt del because whenever I want to boot my laptop it always turn into balckscreen

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on a couple laptops in the past. Windows installed an updated driver with an unsupported resolution. The simplest fix is to plug in an external display and use that to adjust the resolution back to a supported value. You may need to use F4 (or a different key if your keyboard layout has a different key assigned) to enable screen mirroring. If you have TeamViewer or another remote support solution that you can use to access it from another computer you can use that instead of another monitor.

After you have the display fixed go to Windows Explorer, right-click on This PC, select properties, click Advanced, then Hardware, then Device Installation Settings, and finally select No. This will prevent this from happening again.